# Limit Calculation $\lim_{x\to \infty} x\log(x^2+x)- x^2\log(x +1)$

Tags: limits, indeterminate-forms

I am having a problem with the calculation of the following limit. I need to find

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} x\log(x^2+x)- x^2\log(x +1).$$

I've been trying in this way but I'm not sure if it is correct:

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} x\log(x(x+1))- x^2\log(x +1)$$

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} x\log(x)+x\log(x+1)- x^2\log(x +1)$$
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} x\log(x)+\lim_{x\to \infty}\log(x+1) (x- x^2)$$

the first one it should be  $+\infty $  , How could I calculate the second one?

Comment: Hint: $x^2\log(x+1)\gg x\log(x+1)\geqslant x\log(x)$.

Comment: By the way, $\log(x+1)\approx x+1$ is frankly wrong.

Comment: So I should say that :  $\approx\lim_{x\to \infty} - x^2\log(x +1)= -\infty$

Comment: Then you have $\infty - \infty$ which is indeterminate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lim_\limits{x\to \infty} x\log(x^2+x)- x^2\log(x +1)\\
\lim_\limits{x\to \infty} \log\frac{(x^2+x)^x}{(x +1)^{x^2}}\\
\lim_\limits{x\to \infty} \log\frac{x^x}{(x+1)^{x^2-x}}\\
$

The denominator of that fraction is growing much faster than the numerator.
As $x\to\infty$ the limit approaches $\log 0 = -\infty$

Comment: Really, you shouldn't write $\lim$ until you've shown the limit exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the substitution $x=1/t$ that brings the limit into
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\left(
\frac{1}{t}\log\left(\frac{1}{t^2}+\frac{1}{t}\right)
-\frac{1}{t^2}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{t}\right)
\right)
=
\lim_{t\to0^+}
\frac{t\log(1+t)-2t\log t-\log(1+t)+\log t}{t^2}
$$
Since $\lim_{t\to0^+}\log(1+t)=0$ and also $\lim_{t\to0}t\log t=0$, the limit is $-\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

For large $x$, $x\log(x^2+x)$ behaves like $2x\log x$ while $x^2\log(x+1)$ behaves like $x^2\log(x)$, hence the limit is trivially $-\infty$.